# StackOverflowException when trying to retrieve generic list from property

Tags: c#, asp.net

Property in UserControl:

```
     public JobQuote quote
{
    get 
    {
        if (ViewState["Quote"] != null)
            return (JobQuote)ViewState["Quote"];
        else
        {
            JobQuote newQuote = new JobQuote();
            return newQuote;
        }   
    }
    set { ViewState["Quote"] = value; }
}
```

Code being run in UserControl:

```
protected void button_UploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploader.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            quote.JobFileNames.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUploader.FileName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label_UploadStatus.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded.  <br />The following error occurred: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Property from JobQuote.cs class:

```
public List<string> JobFileNames
{
    get 
    {
            return JobFileNames;
    }
    set { JobFileNames = value; }
}
```

The exception is being thrown in the Try block when the code tries to access the JobFileNames property of the JobQuote class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter and setter of the `JobFileNames` property are referencing themselves, causing an infinite loop. When that loop exhausts the available stack space you get a `StackOverflowException`.

You probably need some sort of backing field for the property. Either explicit...

```
private List<string> _jobFileNames;
public List<string> JobFileNames
{
    get { return _jobFileNames; }
    set { _jobFileNames = value; }
}
```

...or, better still,  auto-implemented...

```
public List<string> JobFileNames { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JobFileNames` property is returning itself.
You need to create a backing field and return that, or use an auto-generated property.

Answer (score 0):

In `JobQuote.cs`, `JobFileNames` refers to itself.

You are recursing over the property infinitely.

Use [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) instead:

```
public List<string> JobFileNames { get; set;}
```